# How to allow for bi-directional communication in iOS view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Let me first frame my situation. I have a ViewController, which retains an instance of a `GameManager`. The `GameManager` class encapsulates the state and logic of a simple game. When certain states are encountered in the `GameManager`, I would like to perform a set of actions. For instance: when a game is over, I would like to display a game over dialog. As mentioned above, the game logic resides in the `GameManager`, but the method to create and position a new 'game over' dialog resides in the ViewController. To allow for the `GameManager` to 'call' back into the ViewController, I passed a reference to the ViewController to the `GameManager` when allocated, and simply invoke methods on the ViewController. For example:

```
// GameManager.m
- (void) gameOver {
    [self.viewController showGameOver];
}
```

My question is: Is this the proper, objective-c way to do this? Is there a purer way to handle this? I've though using blocks may be more appropriate.

Comment: Not necessarily your question, but make sure that you have a `weak` attribute on that `self.viewController` reference.  Otherwise, because `viewController` holds on to `gameController` and `gameController` holds on to `viewController` neither will let go and you'll get memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I figured the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement a `delegation` pattern here

In your GameManager

```
@protocol MyGameDelegate : <NSObject>

@required

- (void)gameManager(GameManager *)gameManager gameOverWithSuccess:(BOOL)success;

@end
```

and declare a property

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) id <MyGameDelegate> gameDelagate;
```

in your viewContoller class

```
//  MyGameDelegate implementation

- (void)gameManager(GameManager *)gameManager gameOverWithSuccess:(BOOL)success {

    if (success) [self.viewController showGameOver];
}
```

do something like this but be careful

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) id <MyGameDelegate> gameDelagate;
```

there you are `not` using `strong`

Finally set gameDelagate as your viewcontroller

hope you have understood.

Comment: This is great. I really appreciate the explanation. It works as is now, but I'm always looking for the most appropriate way to handle things. This really helps.